# implementing a AJAX chat site

Tags: java, asp.net, ajax, jsp, chat

I want to implement a chat site with following features:

1. Direct one-on-one chat with a randomly picked stranger
2. If my conversation partner gets disconnected, I should be shifted to different stranger

In short, I want to imitate http://omegle.com/

Which language is best suited to this task? Jsp and Java? PHP? ASP? Others?

Should all of the messages go through the web server, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look into [Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). Ryan Dewsbury's book ["Google Web Toolkit Applications"](http://www.gwtapps.com/) actually runs you through the process of writing a basic chat application.

GWT lets you write Java code that is compiled into Javascript for AJAX applications.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an AJAX Chat tutorial years ago at:

http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Driven_Web_Chat-271_290_291.html

I also did a JSON version of it too:

http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/JSON_AJAX_Web_Chat-271_290_324.html

Those are written in PHP but the back end is really simple so you can port it to whatever language you want easily.  Here's a version that I converted to ASP.NET

http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Web_Chat_ASP_NET-271_290_328.html

It works pretty much like Omegle, all you need to do is setup the code to randomly select a stranger.

Comment: Thanks for the post, It gave me ideas for GAE Chat.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a chat script using PHP + AJAX. Yes, all of my chat messages went through the server because it used AJAX and server-side PHP scripting to deliver the messages to the recipient(s).

For an example of a PHP chat script, see:
http://www.phpfreechat.net/

Comment: Note: PHP isn't necessarily the best language for the task. That is subjective, and I didn't delve into that topic in my post.